# Google Admob stops showing Ads in my app after a view days

Tags: swift, admob

I have implemented Google AdMob in my app. A few days advertising was also displayed. But after some time no more. I probably went through almost all tutorials, YouTube videos and help pages. I can't find any error.
Bank details are verified, account was verified with pin, I have no rule violations etc.

- When I put the code in a test app, it shows ads.
- If I use the app ID of my app store app in the test app - ads are
  displayed.
- If I use App ID and Banner ID in the test app - ads are not
  displayed.
- If I use the correct App ID and Banner ID in the App Store app - no
  ads, no errors in the Console.
- If I use the test App ID and test Banner ID in the App Store app - no
  ads, and Google.dummy.device error

Console Log:
021-10-12 20:07:29.577809+0200 Flaschengeld free[937:142380]  - [I-ACS025031] AdMob App ID changed. Original, new: (nil), MyAppIDNumber

2021-10-12 20:07:29.673816+0200 Flaschengeld free[937:142373]  - [I-ACS023007] Analytics v.80800000 started

2021-10-12 20:07:29.673961+0200 Flaschengeld free[937:142373]  - [I-ACS023008] To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -APMAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see http)

2021-10-12 20:07:29.698650+0200 Flaschengeld free[937:142138] Writing analzed variants.

2021-10-12 20:07:29.706984+0200 Flaschengeld free[937:142380]  - [I-ACS800023] No pending snapshot to activate. SDK name: app_measurement

2021-10-12 20:07:29.769914+0200 Flaschengeld free[937:142383]  - [I-ACS023012] Analytics collection enabled

Could the data in my AdMob dashboard be broken at Google?
Are there any other ways or debug options I can look for the error?
Google always refers to the community when I try to contact them....
I appreciate any ideas :-)

Comment: If I use the app ID of my app store app in the test app - ads are displayed.
With the above cause. You are getting test ads or live ones ??

Comment: neither nor :-(.  I've described the different test directly in my question

Comment: If I use my regulary AdMob Ad ID in my test app an want to display test ads on my registered test device - works well. Same with an valid banner ID - no ads

Comment: Are you able to compare the below changes from your previously working status?

(i)Is there any latest IOS update on your physical device
(ii)Admob SDK version is updated from your side 
(iii)Xcode version is updated.
(iv)New keys/id are generated for banners, Video, or interstitial ads
(v)Is your application live on Itunes?? If yes then I can test it on my device. Maybe it's related to the IOS version.
(vi)Any pod changes in your existing store project.

Comment: Hi Umair, when the error occurred, there were no changes. It just happened from one day to the next. 
In the meantime, I have of course installed iOS 15.0.1 and 15.0.2.
Likewise, I created a new banner ad, but it didn't help.
The error occurs on an iPhone X, 12 Pro Max, iPad Pro and was compiled with Xcode from three different devices.

Comment: You are referring to "test app" from the official Admob GitHub page or do you create a new test project is created from your own side? 
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples

Is your application live on AppStore as Admob state the below changes

"Upcoming changes to AdMob apps. Soon all apps that are monetized in AdMob must be linked to at least one supported app store. To prevent any interruption in ad serving, we recommend that you add your apps to a supported app store now."

Did you set "app-ads.txt" for this specific app??

Comment: It's also good to create a new dummy test application from your AdMob portal and use its ads id's for test purposes, so that we can confirm that your AdMob account is serving ads properly

Comment: Yes, app-ads.txt is set an verified.

Comment: This was my idea, too. Setting up a new app in the AdMob dashboard. I‘m building an app actually and give it a new try if it’s ready. I don’t want to set up a dummy app. As far as I know it’s impossible to remove apps from the AdMob dashboard. If the new app works as expected the problem with my first app has to be at google…

Comment: You are correct we can just hide but can't remove any AdMob application. Let me know if it's working otherwise we will explore other options. Thanks

Comment: Hi Umair, many thanks for your support. I will respond if I uploaded my new app

Comment: Hi all, a small update to my problem: since 6th of December AdMob show impressions for requests from my app. I've done nothing since the problem occurs and didn't upload an update to the App Store. So for now I have requests and impressions but no income. Don't understand AdMob :-)

Comment: Hi,
Glad, that they are working now.
Are you sure that you are not using them in test mode by using test ids?

Comment: Thank you Umair, now the dashboard shows some revenue. It seems to work fine. But I really don't know where the problem was. after nearly three months its starts to run without any action from my side. maybe magic :-)

Comment: Still annoying: After a view days, AdMob my app stops showing ads again. without any changes. Maybe there is no error in the app. is it possible, AdMob doesn't want to deliver ads if my app has not enough users or downloads? if this could be the cause I could stop searching for a problem on my site...